# pythagorean theorem for conditional experience

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let G be a subsigma algebra and X is squareintegrable:

=> $ E[X²] = E[(X-E[X|G])²] + E[E[X|G]²]$

I know that this can be directly shown interpreting the conditional experience as a projection in $L^2$. Is there also another way to show it?

Comment: If I can prove these two things: \\ X squareintegrable => $E[X|G]$ is squareintegrable\\ and \\ $|X| < c => \exists C s.t. E[X|G] < C$, \\ then I can prove the theorem